# Ray-Triangle intersection picking not working

Tags: iphone, objective-c, math, opengl-es

I've been working on this for the past several days and have been stuck. I need to be able to touch the screen and return the x,y,z coordinates of the point on my model closest to the near plane that intersects the ray generated at the pick point. I think part of my problem is I'm doing a bunch of matrix transformations and rotations throughout the render code for my model, although the geometry I'm interested in is all rendered at a specific transformation state. My code that I'm using is below. If anyone can help me figure out how to get this working, that would be awesome. checkCollision() is fed the point that the user clicks on, and gluUnProject() is supposed to transform my 2d pick point into 3D coordinates on my near and far planes, 0 being the near plane and 1 being the far plane. My usage is here and is called right before the geometry is rendered, so all transforms have already been applied:

```
[self checkCollision:touchPoint panVector:panVec];
```

This code below is the collision checking code:

```
-(Boolean) checkCollision:(CGPoint)winPos panVector:(Vector3f*)panVec
{   
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);

winPos.y = (float)viewport[3] - winPos.y;

Vector3f nearPoint;
Vector3f farPoint;

glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);

//Retreiving position projected on near plane
gluUnProject(winPos.x, winPos.y , 0, modelview, projection, viewport, &nearPoint.x, &nearPoint.y, &nearPoint.z);

//Retreiving position projected on far plane
gluUnProject(winPos.x, winPos.y,  1, modelview, projection, viewport, &farPoint.x, &farPoint.y, &farPoint.z);

Vector3f *near = [[Vector3f alloc] initWithFloatsX:nearPoint.x Y:nearPoint.y Z:nearPoint.z];
Vector3f *far = [[Vector3f alloc] initWithFloatsX:farPoint.x Y:farPoint.y Z:farPoint.z];
Vector3f *d = [Vector3f subtractV1:far minusV2:near];

Vector3f *v0 = [[Vector3f alloc] init];
Vector3f *v1 = [[Vector3f alloc] init];
Vector3f *v2 = [[Vector3f alloc] init];
Vector3f *e1; // = [[Vector3f alloc] init];
Vector3f *e2; // = [[Vector3f alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i < assemblyObj->numObjects; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < assemblyObj->partList[i].numVertices; j+=18) {
        v0.x = assemblyObj->partList[i].vertices[j+0];
        v0.y = assemblyObj->partList[i].vertices[j+1];
        v0.z = assemblyObj->partList[i].vertices[j+2];

        v1.x = assemblyObj->partList[i].vertices[j+6];
        v1.y = assemblyObj->partList[i].vertices[j+7];
        v1.z = assemblyObj->partList[i].vertices[j+8];

        v2.x = assemblyObj->partList[i].vertices[j+12];
        v2.y = assemblyObj->partList[i].vertices[j+13];
        v2.z = assemblyObj->partList[i].vertices[j+14];

        e1 = [Vector3f subtractV1:v1 minusV2:v0];
        e2 = [Vector3f subtractV1:v2 minusV2:v0];

        Vector3f *p = [[Vector3f alloc] init];
        [Vector3f cross:p V1:d V2:e2];
        float a = [Vector3f dot:e1 V2:p];
        if (a > -.000001 && a < .000001) {
            continue;
        }

        float f = 1/a;
        Vector3f *s = [Vector3f subtractV1:near minusV2:v0];
        float u = f*([Vector3f dot:s V2:p]);
        if (u<0 || u>1) {
            continue;
        }
        Vector3f *q = [[Vector3f alloc] init];
        [Vector3f cross:q V1:s V2:e1];
        float v = f*([Vector3f dot:d V2:q]);
        if (v<0 || (u+v)>1) {
            continue;
        }
        //NSLog(@"hit polygon");
        return true;
    }
}

//NSLog(@"didn't hit polygon");
return FALSE;   
}  


GLint gluUnProject(GLfloat winx, GLfloat winy, GLfloat winz,
         const GLfloat model[16], const GLfloat proj[16],
         const GLint viewport[4],
         GLfloat * objx, GLfloat * objy, GLfloat * objz)
{
/* matrice de transformation */
GLfloat m[16], A[16];
GLfloat in[4], out[4];

/* transformation coordonnees normalisees entre -1 et 1 */
in[0] = (winx - viewport[0]) * 2 / viewport[2] - 1.f;
in[1] = (winy - viewport[1]) * 2 / viewport[3] - 1.f;
in[2] = 2 * winz - 1.f;
in[3] = 1.f;

/* calcul transformation inverse */
matmul(A, proj, model);
invert_matrix(A, m);

/* d'ou les coordonnees objets */
transform_point(out, m, in);
if (out[3] == 0.f)
    return GL_FALSE;
*objx = out[0] / out[3];
*objy = out[1] / out[3];
*objz = out[2] / out[3];
return GL_TRUE;
}


void transform_point(GLfloat out[4], const GLfloat m[16], const GLfloat in[4])
{
#define M(row,col)  m[col*4+row]
out[0] =
M(0, 0) * in[0] + M(0, 1) * in[1] + M(0, 2) * in[2] + M(0, 3) * in[3];
out[1] =
M(1, 0) * in[0] + M(1, 1) * in[1] + M(1, 2) * in[2] + M(1, 3) * in[3];
out[2] =
M(2, 0) * in[0] + M(2, 1) * in[1] + M(2, 2) * in[2] + M(2, 3) * in[3];
out[3] =
M(3, 0) * in[0] + M(3, 1) * in[1] + M(3, 2) * in[2] + M(3, 3) * in[3];
#undef M
}

void matmul(GLfloat * product, const GLfloat * a, const GLfloat * b)
{
/* This matmul was contributed by Thomas Malik */
GLfloat temp[16];
GLint i;

#define A(row,col)  a[(col<<2)+row]
#define B(row,col)  b[(col<<2)+row]
#define T(row,col)  temp[(col<<2)+row]

/* i-te Zeile */
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    T(i, 0) =
    A(i, 0) * B(0, 0) + A(i, 1) * B(1, 0) + A(i, 2) * B(2, 0) + A(i,
                                                                  3) *
    B(3, 0);
    T(i, 1) =
    A(i, 0) * B(0, 1) + A(i, 1) * B(1, 1) + A(i, 2) * B(2, 1) + A(i,
                                                                  3) *
    B(3, 1);
    T(i, 2) =
    A(i, 0) * B(0, 2) + A(i, 1) * B(1, 2) + A(i, 2) * B(2, 2) + A(i,
                                                                  3) *
    B(3, 2);
    T(i, 3) =
    A(i, 0) * B(0, 3) + A(i, 1) * B(1, 3) + A(i, 2) * B(2, 3) + A(i,
                                                                  3) *
    B(3, 3);
}

#undef A
#undef B
#undef T
memcpy(product, temp, 16 * sizeof(GLfloat));
}

int invert_matrix(const GLfloat * m, GLfloat * out)
{
/* NB. OpenGL Matrices are COLUMN major. */
#define SWAP_ROWS(a, b) { GLfloat *_tmp = a; (a)=(b); (b)=_tmp; }
#define MAT(m,r,c) (m)[(c)*4+(r)]

GLfloat wtmp[4][8];
GLfloat m0, m1, m2, m3, s;
GLfloat *r0, *r1, *r2, *r3;

r0 = wtmp[0], r1 = wtmp[1], r2 = wtmp[2], r3 = wtmp[3];

r0[0] = MAT(m, 0, 0), r0[1] = MAT(m, 0, 1),
r0[2] = MAT(m, 0, 2), r0[3] = MAT(m, 0, 3),
r0[4] = 1.f, r0[5] = r0[6] = r0[7] = 0.f,
r1[0] = MAT(m, 1, 0), r1[1] = MAT(m, 1, 1),
r1[2] = MAT(m, 1, 2), r1[3] = MAT(m, 1, 3),
r1[5] = 1.f, r1[4] = r1[6] = r1[7] = 0.f,
r2[0] = MAT(m, 2, 0), r2[1] = MAT(m, 2, 1),
r2[2] = MAT(m, 2, 2), r2[3] = MAT(m, 2, 3),
r2[6] = 1.f, r2[4] = r2[5] = r2[7] = 0.f,
r3[0] = MAT(m, 3, 0), r3[1] = MAT(m, 3, 1),
r3[2] = MAT(m, 3, 2), r3[3] = MAT(m, 3, 3),
r3[7] = 1.f, r3[4] = r3[5] = r3[6] = 0.f;

/* choose pivot - or die */
if (fabsf(r3[0]) > fabsf(r2[0]))
    SWAP_ROWS(r3, r2);
if (fabsf(r2[0]) > fabsf(r1[0]))
    SWAP_ROWS(r2, r1);
if (fabsf(r1[0]) > fabsf(r0[0]))
    SWAP_ROWS(r1, r0);
if (0.f == r0[0])
    return GL_FALSE;

/* eliminate first variable     */
m1 = r1[0] / r0[0];
m2 = r2[0] / r0[0];
m3 = r3[0] / r0[0];
s = r0[1];
r1[1] -= m1 * s;
r2[1] -= m2 * s;
r3[1] -= m3 * s;
s = r0[2];
r1[2] -= m1 * s;
r2[2] -= m2 * s;
r3[2] -= m3 * s;
s = r0[3];
r1[3] -= m1 * s;
r2[3] -= m2 * s;
r3[3] -= m3 * s;
s = r0[4];
if (s != 0.f) {
    r1[4] -= m1 * s;
    r2[4] -= m2 * s;
    r3[4] -= m3 * s;
}
s = r0[5];
if (s != 0.f) {
    r1[5] -= m1 * s;
    r2[5] -= m2 * s;
    r3[5] -= m3 * s;
}
s = r0[6];
if (s != 0.f) {
    r1[6] -= m1 * s;
    r2[6] -= m2 * s;
    r3[6] -= m3 * s;
}
s = r0[7];
if (s != 0.f) {
    r1[7] -= m1 * s;
    r2[7] -= m2 * s;
    r3[7] -= m3 * s;
}

/* choose pivot - or die */
if (fabsf(r3[1]) > fabsf(r2[1]))
    SWAP_ROWS(r3, r2);
if (fabsf(r2[1]) > fabsf(r1[1]))
    SWAP_ROWS(r2, r1);
if (0.f == r1[1])
    return GL_FALSE;

/* eliminate second variable */
m2 = r2[1] / r1[1];
m3 = r3[1] / r1[1];
r2[2] -= m2 * r1[2];
r3[2] -= m3 * r1[2];
r2[3] -= m2 * r1[3];
r3[3] -= m3 * r1[3];
s = r1[4];
if (0.f != s) {
    r2[4] -= m2 * s;
    r3[4] -= m3 * s;
}
s = r1[5];
if (0.f != s) {
    r2[5] -= m2 * s;
    r3[5] -= m3 * s;
}
s = r1[6];
if (0.f != s) {
    r2[6] -= m2 * s;
    r3[6] -= m3 * s;
}
s = r1[7];
if (0.f != s) {
    r2[7] -= m2 * s;
    r3[7] -= m3 * s;
}

/* choose pivot - or die */
if (fabs(r3[2]) > fabs(r2[2]))
    SWAP_ROWS(r3, r2);
if (0.f == r2[2])
    return GL_FALSE;

/* eliminate third variable */
m3 = r3[2] / r2[2];
r3[3] -= m3 * r2[3], r3[4] -= m3 * r2[4],
r3[5] -= m3 * r2[5], r3[6] -= m3 * r2[6], r3[7] -= m3 * r2[7];

/* last check */
if (0.f == r3[3])
    return GL_FALSE;

s = 1.f / r3[3];        /* now back substitute row 3 */
r3[4] *= s;
r3[5] *= s;
r3[6] *= s;
r3[7] *= s;

m2 = r2[3];         /* now back substitute row 2 */
s = 1.f / r2[2];
r2[4] = s * (r2[4] - r3[4] * m2), r2[5] = s * (r2[5] - r3[5] * m2),
r2[6] = s * (r2[6] - r3[6] * m2), r2[7] = s * (r2[7] - r3[7] * m2);
m1 = r1[3];
r1[4] -= r3[4] * m1, r1[5] -= r3[5] * m1,
r1[6] -= r3[6] * m1, r1[7] -= r3[7] * m1;
m0 = r0[3];
r0[4] -= r3[4] * m0, r0[5] -= r3[5] * m0,
r0[6] -= r3[6] * m0, r0[7] -= r3[7] * m0;

m1 = r1[2];         /* now back substitute row 1 */
s = 1.f / r1[1];
r1[4] = s * (r1[4] - r2[4] * m1), r1[5] = s * (r1[5] - r2[5] * m1),
r1[6] = s * (r1[6] - r2[6] * m1), r1[7] = s * (r1[7] - r2[7] * m1);
m0 = r0[2];
r0[4] -= r2[4] * m0, r0[5] -= r2[5] * m0,
r0[6] -= r2[6] * m0, r0[7] -= r2[7] * m0;

m0 = r0[1];         /* now back substitute row 0 */
s = 1.f / r0[0];
r0[4] = s * (r0[4] - r1[4] * m0), r0[5] = s * (r0[5] - r1[5] * m0),
r0[6] = s * (r0[6] - r1[6] * m0), r0[7] = s * (r0[7] - r1[7] * m0);

MAT(out, 0, 0) = r0[4];
MAT(out, 0, 1) = r0[5], MAT(out, 0, 2) = r0[6];
MAT(out, 0, 3) = r0[7], MAT(out, 1, 0) = r1[4];
MAT(out, 1, 1) = r1[5], MAT(out, 1, 2) = r1[6];
MAT(out, 1, 3) = r1[7], MAT(out, 2, 0) = r2[4];
MAT(out, 2, 1) = r2[5], MAT(out, 2, 2) = r2[6];
MAT(out, 2, 3) = r2[7], MAT(out, 3, 0) = r3[4];
MAT(out, 3, 1) = r3[5], MAT(out, 3, 2) = r3[6];
MAT(out, 3, 3) = r3[7];

return GL_TRUE;

#undef MAT
#undef SWAP_ROWS
}
```

## Edit:

I followed Justin Meiners suggestion of rendering points to show me where my pick ray is getting generated and I can see what's happening now, but don't know why. My scene implements arcball rotation, zooming and panning through quaternions. I'll roughly lay out what my scene is doing then what is happening with my pick ray.

First, setup my viewport:

```
glViewport(0, 0, scene.width, scene.height);
glOrthof(-11.25, 11.25, -14.355, 14.355, -1000, 1000);
```

Next, I grab the 16 element matrix that I use as part of my arcball method to navigate my scene and multiply my modelview matrix by it:

```
float mat[16];
[arcball get_Renamed:mat];
glMultMatrixf(mat);
```

Now, I do my pick ray:

```
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projection);
glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelview);

touchPoint.y = (float)viewport[3] - touchPoint.y;

Vector3f nearPoint, farPoint;

//Retreiving position projected on near plane
gluUnProject(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y , 0, modelview, projection, viewport, &nearPoint.x, &nearPoint.y, &nearPoint.z);

//Retreiving position projected on far plane
gluUnProject(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y,  1, modelview, projection, viewport, &farPoint.x, &farPoint.y, &farPoint.z);

float coords[3] = {nearPoint.x, nearPoint.y, nearPoint.z};
float coords2[3] = {farPoint.x, farPoint.y, farPoint.z};

glPointSize(100);
glColor4f(1, 0, 0, 1);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(coords[0])*3, coords);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);

glPointSize(150);
glColor4f(0, 0, 1, 1);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(coords2[0])*3, coords2);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

I do this, and it works fine before I rotate my scene, but as soon as I start to rotate my scene, the far point starts to move around. If I rotate the scene around exactly 180 degrees, the far point is back in line with the near point. Any idea what is going on? The arcball is just based on Ken Shoemake's algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out what I was doing wrong. You have to get the state of GL_VIEWPORT and GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX right after you create them, which is right after the

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
```

calls. If you do this later, then your matrix transformations are affecting your viewport and projection matrices. It doesn't seem like they should, but they do. The only matrix you want to get the state of when you do your picking is the modelview matrix, and you want to do that when your modelview has the same transformations as the geometry you are trying to perform gluUnProject on. Once I figured that out, the ray picking algorithm worked great. On the iPad, it can perform triangle-ray intersection on 15,000 triangles in 19ms, which equates to about 800,000 intersections per second. Not too bad for an iPad, although I'm sure performance could be improved by precomputing triangle plane equations. Thanks for the suggestions, they helped me to figure out what was going on so I could fix it.

Answer (score 3):

You should draw your mouse ray with GL_LINES to make sure it looks right. This will save your life and you can tweek matricies and stuff to try and get it right. Also if your doing alot of transformations then you need to call glUnProject inside those so it takes into account those. You might have to save the mouse position until you can unproject it in the next render loop. EG

```
glPushMatrix();

// Rotate world
glRotate(...)

// Mouse glGetIntv, and glGetFloatV here

drawObject()
```

Sample Drawing code (Give that Vector is just a struct with float x, y, and z components.

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vector), points);

    glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 2);

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

Comment: How do you draw your mouse ray using GL_LINES? I was trying to do that, but couldn't figure out how. This is OpenGL-ES you're referring to, right? Also, where should I perform glGetIntegerv and glGetFloatv to get the correct matrix values for viewport, projection and modelview?

Comment: Its hard to describe but it needs to be in the rendering loop where you start rendering things. So it has all scene and projection transformations applied when you get it.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, which helped me out a ton. I've posted a follow up to my problem in the original thread above. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm is it just drawing that way? Or is the picking still not working as well?

Comment: The points are just showing me where my pick ray is being drawn. I'm using gluUnProject and that is returning a near and far point. The near point is correct, but for some reason, the far point changes as I rotate the scene, it doesn't stay where I touch. Before I do any rotations, the far point is correct. As soon as I start rotating my scene with my arcball, the far point shifts, moving from the center of the screen in the direction that I drag to rotate the scene. The amount it changes varies with how far apart my near and far point are specified in the third parameter of gluUnProject.

Comment: Well unless your are constantly unprojecting and getting new points, it will rotate with the scene. Are you just unprojecting when they click? (IF you are this is fine you just have to only do hit detections at that point)